# Problem in dotnet tool version installation

Tags: .net, installation, entity-framework-core, nuget, version

I am learning how to build an app with ASPNET Core and Angular. I am using vscode.

I have the dotnet version 3.1.402

I installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite Version="3.1.4" from nuget gallery and then when trying to install dotnet tool as version 3.1.4 using the command:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.4
```

It is not working giving me this error:

```
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'dotnet-ef (>= 3.1.4)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.

error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'dotnet-ef (>= 3.1.4)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1/any'.

The tool package could not be restored. (...)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: check your installations --> dotnet --info